# I am trying to get past Binding RPC on address 1 port 8332 failed

Tags: tor, bitcoin.conf, port, rpc-error-25

My debug file shows:

```
2022-12-17T09:28:00Z Bitcoin Core version v24.0.1 (release build)
2022-12-17T09:28:00Z InitParameterInteraction: parameter interaction: -externalip set -> setting -discover=0
2022-12-17T09:28:00Z Using the 'x86_shani(1way,2way)' SHA256 implementation
2022-12-17T09:28:00Z Using RdSeed as an additional entropy source
2022-12-17T09:28:00Z Using RdRand as an additional entropy source
2022-12-17T09:28:00Z Default data directory /home/rick/.bitcoin
2022-12-17T09:28:00Z Using data directory /home/rick/.bitcoin
2022-12-17T09:28:00Z Config file: /home/rick/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
2022-12-17T09:28:00Z Config file arg: externalip="62676xoz5zt3jdgyjhombuluqf6ucwwoktfcpoc77g7my7yt6p4ua5qd.onion"
2022-12-17T09:28:00Z Config file arg: help-debug="1"
2022-12-17T09:28:00Z Config file arg: listenonion="1"
2022-12-17T09:28:00Z Config file arg: seednode="hhiv5pnxenvbf4am.onion"
2022-12-17T09:28:00Z Config file arg: torcontrol="127.0.01:9051"
2022-12-17T09:28:00Z Config file arg: torpassword=****
2022-12-17T09:28:00Z Using at most 125 automatic connections (1024 file descriptors available)
2022-12-17T09:28:00Z Using 16 MiB out of 16 MiB requested for signature cache, able to store 524288 elements
2022-12-17T09:28:00Z Using 16 MiB out of 16 MiB requested for script execution cache, able to store 524288 elements
2022-12-17T09:28:00Z Script verification uses 7 additional threads
2022-12-17T09:28:00Z scheduler thread start
2022-12-17T09:28:00Z Binding RPC on address ::1 port 8332 failed.
2022-12-17T09:28:00Z Binding RPC on address 127.0.0.1 port 8332 failed.
2022-12-17T09:28:00Z Unable to bind any endpoint for RPC server
2022-12-17T09:28:00Z Error: Unable to start HTTP server. See debug log for details.
Error: Unable to start HTTP server. See debug log for details.
2022-12-17T09:28:00Z Shutdown: In progress...
2022-12-17T09:28:00Z scheduler thread exit
2022-12-17T09:28:00Z Shutdown: done
```

My bitcoin.conf is:

```
 Specify your own public address
externalip=lotsofcharacters.onion
listenonion=1
seednode=hhiv5pnxenvbf4am.onion

torcontrol=127.0.01:9051

# Tor control port password (default: empty)
torpassword=16:LOTSOFCapitalletters
```

Hidden tor password & external ip for privacy.
(they are valid I have been using them on my lightning node)

PLease do you have any suggestions as to what I can do to get the BTC node back??

Comment: Can't tell if tor service is running                                                                  
                lightning_connectd: Connecting stream socket to Tor service: Connection refused
lightningd: connectd failed (exit status 1), exiting.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a service has failed to bind to a high numbered port I have always found it was because another application was already bound to that port. I have always discovered the culprit using `netstat -anp`  or similar.

N.b. High numbered is > 1023

Comment: lightning_connectd: Connecting stream socket to Tor service: Connection refused
lightningd: connectd failed (exit status 1), exiting.